# Mysql UTC format works for "SELECT" but NOT for "UPDATE"

Tags: mysql, timestamp, timezone, utc, gmt

This is the columns "created_at" datatime
[image]

And I can query "created_at" with a UTC time
[image: SELECT]

But alert "Incorrect datatime value" while "UPDATE"
[image: UPDATE]

I don't know, but for UPDATE command, I have to use a 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format, and it works

But still makes no sense to me,

I believe the UTC is more accurate, and if "SELECT" could recognize UTC, why not "UPDATE"?

Comment: Change datatype to timestamp and review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: See `SHOW WARNINGS;` after each query. You'll see that for UPDATE this is an error whereas for SELECT this is a warning. The reason - SELECT cannot damage data, rather than UPDATE. If you'd enable strict SQL mode then SELECT will fail too. You must use correct literal format **ALWAYS**.